# How do I use a class constructor to get a value from a file? C++

Tags: c++, class, object, fstream

sorry if this is obvious, I am new to classes.

I want the code to read the first value of a file from a class constructor (a getter), and right now the constructor returns a random number instead of the first number of the file, so it's clearly not reading the file for some reason.  Thank you for your help, the code is in the following link.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

class bankAccount
{
public:
    int getAcctNum();
    bankAccount(string n);
    bankAccount();

private:
    ifstream sourceFile;
    char tempWord;
    int accountNumber;
    double initialBalance;
    double interestRate;
    double serviceCharge;
    double depositAmt;
    double withdrawAmt;
    double totalDeposits;
    double totalWithdraws;
    double tempAmt;

};
int main()
{
    string fileName;
    cout << "Enter the name of the data file: ";
    cin >> fileName;
    cout << endl;
    bankAccount object(fileName);
    cout << "Account number: " << object.getAcctNum() << endl;
    return 0;
}

bankAccount::bankAccount(string n)
{
    ifstream sourceFile(n.c_str());
}
bankAccount::getAcctNum()
{
    sourceFile >> tempWord;
    sourceFile >> accountNumber;
    return accountNumber;
}
```

The value in the file that it should read is:
# 123456

Comment: Post code here, not via a link.

Comment: fixed, I didn't know that was a rule.

Comment: You constructor has a _local_ variable named `sourceFile` which is different from (and hides) the member variable of the same name. Go read up on the concept of an Initialization List for how to initialize the `sourceFile` member as you apparently intended.

Comment: "Post code here" means "Post readable, logically indented code here", rather than something that must've been typed in on a keyboard with a broken TAB key, resulting in unreadable code.

Comment: Well that's one of the reasons I originally had it in a pastebin.  I lose those white space characters when I paste it here.

Comment: When posting code make use of the `{}` button above the input box or use a block tab to indent all of your code in your IDE before pasting it into the text box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem has to do with **scope**. For a quick TL;DR how do I fix it, just scroll all the way to the bottom.

An easy way to think of **scope** is by thinking: where is my variable defined. A variable defined outside of main is said to have global **scope**, as it's a global variable. That means that no matter where you reference it (after it's definition) it will be defined (*not necessary initialized, however*). If a variable is defined within a function, it's scope is limited to that function. So it will be defined in that function only, not in other functions. If you define a variable within a for loop, or an if statement, or anywhere were you open a new scope using `{ }`, that variable is **scope**-limited, ie it is only defined in that scope, and will stop being defined after the closing brace is read. Here is an example:

```
#include <iostream>
// rest of includes and usings and function prototypes, etc

const string AUTHOR_NAME = "ME"; // this is now defined everywhere in the program.

int main() {
    bool program_busy = true; // this is only defined in main()
}

bool return_program_busy() {
    cout << AUTHOR_NAME << endl; // this works as AUTHOR_NAME is defined
    return program_busy; // this won't work, as program_busy is not defined in this scope.
}

void better_example(bool program_busy) {
     int version = 0.1;
     for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
         do_something(version, i); // this works as both are defined.
     }
     // i is no longer defined as we exited it's scope!!
     if(program_busy) { // this opens a new scope.
         int version = 0.2;
         do_something(version, 0); // wait, is version 0.1 or 0.2???
     }
}
```

As you can undoubtedly see in the last line, there are two versions (with different scopes) that are defined. So which one does it use? The one with the smaller scope, or the more *local* one. version 0.2 is only defined within the `if(program_busy)` scope, so it's smaller than the entire function scope, so it is used. Can you spot the error in your own code now?

`ifstream sourceFile` has two scopes: a global-class one, i.e. it is defined for the entire class, and a local scope for the constructor function you have.

`ifstream sourceFile(n.c_str());` will create a new variable with a limited scope and initalize it, leaving the `sourceFile` with a more global scope uninitialized. The way to fix it is simply **not** redefine the `sourceFile` variable.

TL;DR: change `ifstream sourceFile(n.c_str());` to `sourceFile.open(n.c_str());`